# Problem with group by and aggregate function

Tags: sql, oracle

In this example I noticed when I simply use this:

```
select 
    se.name
from trade t
    JOIN stock_exchange se
        on se.stock_ex_id = t.stock_ex_id
    JOIN stock_listing sl
        ON sl.stock_ex_id = se.stock_ex_id
group by se.name;
```

It would return the rows that I needed. However I need to add a few more columns in the select statement.

Like this:

```
SELECT 
    se.name AS "stock exchange name",
      se.stock_ex_id AS "stock exchange ID",
      sl.stock_symbol AS "stock symbol",
      SUM(t.shares) AS "highest total trade volumn"
    FROM trade t
        join stock_exchange se
            on se.stock_ex_id = t.stock_ex_id
        join stock_listing sl
            on sl.stock_ex_id = se.stock_ex_id and sl.stock_id = t.stock_id
    WHERE t.stock_ex_id is not null
    GROUP BY se.name,se.stock_ex_id, sl.stock_symbol
    HAVING SUM(t.shares) =(
        SELECT 
            MAX(SUM(t.shares))
        FROM(
            SELECT 
                SUM(shares)
            FROM trade tr
            WHERE tr.stock_ex_id is not null
            GROUP BY tr.trade_id
        )
    )
    ORDER BY se.name, sl.stock_symbol;
```

I tested a few times the problem occur when I add in se.stock_ex_id, sl.stock_symbol in the first group by clause. The out put would contain 3 more rows not being the max value of their groups. So how can I work around it?

Comment: Try to add sample data and desired output so that we can understand your problem clearly.. Btw you should try with Window functions.

Comment: Please explain the additional columns you want.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Windows function and put it in the sub query. Below query is not tested so it is just a skeleton:

```
Select * from 
(Select t.*, max(highest) OVER (PARTITION BY tr.trade_id) max_sal from 
(SELECT 
    se.name AS "stock exchange name",
      se.stock_ex_id AS "stock exchange ID",
      sl.stock_symbol AS "stock symbol",
      SUM(t.shares) OVER (PARTITION BY se.name) AS "highest "
    FROM trade t
        join stock_exchange se
            on se.stock_ex_id = t.stock_ex_id
        join stock_listing sl
            on sl.stock_ex_id = se.stock_ex_id and sl.stock_id = t.stock_id
 WHERE t.stock_ex_id is not null) 
 WHERE tr.stock_ex_id is not null) highest = max_Sal;
```

Another one would be:

```
Select * from (SELECT 
        se.name AS "stock exchange name",
          se.stock_ex_id AS "stock exchange ID",
          sl.stock_symbol AS "stock symbol",
          SUM(t.shares) OVER (PARTITION BY se.name) AS "highest "
        FROM trade t
            join stock_exchange se
                on se.stock_ex_id = t.stock_ex_id
            join stock_listing sl
                on sl.stock_ex_id = se.stock_ex_id and sl.stock_id = t.stock_id
     WHERE t.stock_ex_id is not null)
WHERE highest = (SELECT 
            MAX(SUM(t.shares))
        FROM(
            SELECT 
                SUM(shares)
            FROM trade tr
            WHERE tr.stock_ex_id is not null
            GROUP BY tr.trade_id))
order 1,3
```

if you are looking for extra fun you can also try with [this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions#first_and_last)